# How to use a trained learning model (.sav) in ROS python node?

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I created a learning model (by MLP method) by using the Jupyter notebook. Now, I want to use it in a ROS python node. How I can load the trained model?

In Jupyter notebook, I can use the following code to load a trained model:

```
# load the model from disk
1) filename = r"C:\Users\....\TrainedModelName.sav"
2) loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

However, by using code line 1 in the ROS python node, I receive the error. (I changed the address according to the Ubuntu directory)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392401/how-to-use-a-trained-learning-model-(.sav)-in-ros-python-node?/) by [Emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/46656/emad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-07**:
Have you installed the libraries in your system?

**Comment by [Emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/46656/emad/) on 2021-12-19**:
Yes, all were installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using "~" for the directory. When I used "home/my username/" the problem was solved.

---

Originally posted by [Emad](https://answers.ros.org/users/46656/emad/) with karma: 16 on 2021-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-19**:
Glad you found the issue. Thank you for sharing